# Regular Expression for Special Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regular expression specifies the input format to the user. As of now it works well for digits and alphabets.Though I want to exclude only forward slash. Below is the regular expression

```
"format": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

Now I want to include all special characters apart from slash (/) I added them next to 9, it works but when I adds "+$" it doesn't work because those are included in building the regular expression and they have a meaning for it.
How can I include them in the regular expression?

Comment: You need to escape the forward slash. `\/`.

Comment: And escape `]`, too (if you also added that symbol). Also, if you have a double  quote, you can write it as `\x22`. But your question is still unclear. Please post your real expression (as it looks now).

Comment: What are "special characters"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a negated class will suit your needs :

```
"format": "^[^/]+$"
```

This will accept anything but `/`, which includes the previously defined a-zA-Z0-9 and all special characters but `/`.

That said, I'm not sure you really want to accept any special character.

Example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mY6uI7/1).

Comment: How can I exclude forward slash in this negated class as well ?

Comment: It is excluded already, that's the point of a negated class : you open it with `[^`, list all the characters you want to exclude, and close with `]` ; the resulting class will only match the characters that are *not* listed.

Comment: I added an example, hope you understand